# Upload file from php to ftp server

Tags: php, server, ftp, upload

I'm using a script to upload file via php script to my ftp server.
The connection is ok but every time i try to upload files it says:
Error uploading file! Please try again later.

so it seems that there is something wrong in the script.

Directory destination is mydomain/test/upload/
and the script is into: mydomain/test/index.php

Anyone of you can help me to understand?

```
// ftp settings
$ftp_hostname = 'xxxx'; // change this
$ftp_username = 'xxxx'; // change this
$ftp_password = 'xxxx'; // change this
$remote_dir = '/upload/'; // change this
$src_file = $_FILES['srcfile']['name'];


if ($src_file!='')
{
    // remote file path
    $dst_file = $remote_dir . $src_file;
    
    // connect ftp
    $ftpcon = ftp_connect($ftp_hostname) or die('Error connecting to ftp server...');
    
    // ftp login
    $ftplogin = ftp_login($ftpcon, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
    
    // ftp upload
    if (ftp_put($ftpcon, $dst_file, $src_file, FTP_ASCII))
        echo 'File uploaded successfully to FTP server!';
    else
        echo 'Error uploading file! Please try again later.';
    
    // close ftp stream
    ftp_close($ftpcon);
}
else
    header('Location: index.php');
```

and the index file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Files to FTP Server in PHP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 well" style="background:none;">
    <form action="ftp_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <legend>Please Choose File to Upload</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="srcfile" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File to FTP Server" class="btn btn-warning"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have uploaded file into the upload folder:
mydomain/test/upload/

Comment: Hello, could you try catch your code ?

Comment: i set the ftpmode to passive and the result is
`Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /web/htdocs/www.xxxx.com/home/test/ftp_upload.php on line 31

Warning: ftp_put(): TYPE is now ASCII in /web/htdocs/www.xxxx.com/home/test/ftp_upload.php on line 31
There was a problem while uploading`

Comment: passive mode: 
`// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($connect, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");
    echo "Connected!<br/>"; `

Comment: but is there an example that works in order i can compare and check where is the error?

Comment: Do not post information in comments (delete them), edit everything into your question. Show us where did you place the `ftp_pasv` call + You didn't seem to try the `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS` suggestion. + Can you upload the file using any FTP client running on the machine, where you PHP code fails?

Answer (score -1):

Either the source file is incorrect, or your FTP sits behind a firewall.

If it's behind a firewall, try this [ftp-pasv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)

Comment: i also set passive mode. No result. The connection is ok. It's when it uploads the file into the destination folder.

Comment: Have you var_dump($src_file) ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).